# Comparing nested list and finding index of value match

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested, compare

I'm looking to find matches within a nested list based off the 1st index, and add the floats of each of the lists that strike a match.

Say I have this nested list:

`a = [[1234, 5678, 4.5], [0987, 6543, 6.8], [4321, 5678, 9.8]]`

I'm looking for a way to find a match for the 1st index within a list with another list within "a", and once the match is found add up the values of the 2nd index.

I've attempted plenty of ways to check for matches, such as nested for loops, the any() function, and stuff such as:

```
match = []

if a[x][1] in a[0:-1][1]:
   a.pop(x)
   match.append(x)
```

to create a new list based off the matches and compare them that way, but it never seems to work.
All of these methods seem to just return if a match occurred, and not the specific index associated with the match.

Should I create a dictionary with the keys being the 1st index and the value being the 2nd index and compare that way? Or is there some other way to check for the index of the matches and compare within a loop?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be the summation of all the floats in the second index associated with the particular value of the first index in the nested list. This is why I need to find the index of the matches, as they will allow me to sum the 2nd index from each list that matched

Comment: Floats are in the third index not the second

Comment: Oh yeah sorry you're right, I was thinking of it more in the order of 0,1,2.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the exact output you expect from your sample data and an explanation of how that output is generated.

Comment: Alright I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested at the end of your question you can use a dictionary to do what you want to, using the 1st index value as the key and 2nd index as the value. Iterate through your list of lists, storing the item in the dictionary. If it already exists add the values.

```
a = [[1234, 5678, 4.5], [987, 6543, 6.8], [4321, 5678, 9.8]]
d = {}
for l in a:
    id = l[1]
    if id not in d:
        d[id] = l[2]
    else:
        d[id] += l[2]
print(*d.items())
```

Output:

```
(5678, 14.3) (6543, 6.8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I needed!